# 3 queries to merge and planning to create graph

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Product_Name: Pillow, Pillow Case
Color: Red, Blue and Green
Status: Available, Sold
```

I have 3 individual queries that counts the ff:

1. Count the Total numbers of pillows available
2. Count the Total numbers pillows sold
3. Difference between Available over Sold

I'm planning to create a graph about the individual queries but can't figure out **to merge the 3 queries into 1** that still results to the same output or **is it possible?**

**1 of the queries:** *(I'll just add Where condition for the Status = 'Sold')*

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS totalAvailable, Product_Name, Color, Status 
FROM Product
GROUP BY Product, Color
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Product_name,
        totalAvailable,
        totalSold,
        totalAvailable - totalSold AS ProductDifference
FROM
        (
            SELECT  Product_name,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalAvailable,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Sold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalSold
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY Product_name
        ) s
```

Comment: I actually getting confuse with your answer :) because of the 'SUM'  but it really works! I really appreciate it. Do you mind giving me a brief explanation why using SUM instead of COUNT? or site link?

Comment: Basically the query returns all records from the table. execute this line: `SELECT  Product_name, 
  Status, 
        CASE WHEN Status = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Available,
        CASE WHEN Status = 'Sold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Sold
FROM    tableName` you will see the values for the status. The values will then be calculated through `SUM()`.